# Emacs: how do I read my keybindings?

Tags: emacs

How do I read read `isearch-mode-map` and `global-map` variables? With `C-h v` they are displayed in an unreadable form.

**Edit**:

`C-h b` is also useful in finding keybindings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`substitute-command-keys` will format a keymap nicely.  To wit:

```lisp
(defun le::describe-keymap (kmap-sym)
  (interactive "Skeymap:")
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer (format "*keymap: %s*" kmap-sym)
    (print (substitute-command-keys (format "\\{%s}" kmap-sym)))))
```